# Retrieving values from a multidimensional JSON array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, nsjsonserialization

Hi i am trying to get the subject name value out of the following JSON file (dataArray), which I have already run through NSJSONSERIALISATION:

```
-0:  {
id: "55edc05848177ec741daf79e"
firstName: "Brad"
rating: 4.2
lessons: 5
text: "Lessons, they're yours take it"
-subjects: [4]
     -0:  {
     name: "Indonesian"
     pricePerHour: "500000"
     }
     -1:  {
     name: "Diving"
     pricePerHour: "700000"
     }
```

But am not able to access if using the indexPath and dot notation I have used for other elements. I'm understanding it must because I have to access an NSDictionary element within two arrays, however haven't been able to find the correct code to do this (though have looked a lot on here, most examples are for much simpler cases).
Here is the code I have been trying, but as I mentioned I now see that this code doesn't cover the array within array of the JSON. How should I modify this to get the value:

```
// Load and display subjects
    UILabel *subjectLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    NSString * subject1String = [dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath: @"subjects.0.name"];

    subjectLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subject1String];
```

Comment: its not a valid `JSON` data, you can verify your json using [this site](http://www.jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not valid Json. Print response as you are getting from the server end. And for getting **name :** you need to add loop.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the loop you are mentioning? Regarding the Json this is fine, it works ok on our website and I can read all other information into my ios app, just the subjects that I am having trouble with

Comment: Try this method for fetching your names

NSArray *arr = [self.data valueForKeyPath:@“-0.subjects"];
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *p in arr) {
    [str appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", p.valueForKey:@“name"]
]
}